# How do you create a batch file to run a command in Command Prompt

Tags: windows-7, batch

I want a batch file that will open Command prompt and then "tracert google.com". How can I do this on Windows 7?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: @DragonLord - apparently, we *are* a code-writing service.

Answer (score 2):

Open notepad.exe, type `tracert google.com`, save as `filename.bat` (or as `filename.txt` and then rename it to `filename.bat`), double click the file.

Comment: you are forgetting something very important...

Comment: @Keltari What, keeping the window open after completion? I was hoping to make Arthur work for it a little more, considering the low quality of his original question. Maybe even turn it into a learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your batch file:

```
cmd.exe /k tracert google.com
```

This will open the command prompt, run the `tracert` command, and leave the command prompt open.